# Cue ball direction after collision

Tags: unity, physics, collision-resolution, linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out the velocity of ball A after collision, which is V2.A as seen in the figure. I know that the velocity of ball A is perpendicular to the line connecting centre of ball A and B when the collision occurs.

[image: Diagram of two colliding balls]
(Image taken from: http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-billiards.html)

The issue is, my V2.A is sometimes flipped in the opposite direction, and I can't seem to figure out the issue here. Here's my V2.A calculation

```
Vector2 diff = (b - a).normalized;  
Vector2 perpendiular = Vector2.Perpendicular(diff);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Vector2.Perpendicular](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Perpendicular.html):

> Returns the 2D vector perpendicular to this 2D vector. The result is always rotated 90-degrees in a **counter-clockwise direction** for a 2D coordinate system where the positive Y axis goes up.

In this case, just judge whether the unsigned angle between the velocity vector of ball A and the result vector is greater than 90 degrees:

```
Vector2 diff = (b - a).normalized;
Vector2 perpendiular = Vector2.Perpendicular(diff);
if (Vector2.Angle(directionOfA, perpendiular) > 90)
{
    perpendiular = -perpendiular;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You can also treat this as a vector projection.

```
Vector2 collisionAxis = (b - a).normalized;

// Get the component of the velocity vector pointing into B.
float parallelSpeed = Vector2.Dot(collisionAxis, velocityA);

// Subtract that component to leave only the portion perpendicular.
Vector2 remainingVelocity = velocityA - collisionAxis * parallelSpeed;
```

This method works without computing an angle or branching.